# How to debug further for ntdll!RtlDeactivateActivationContextUnsafeFast?

Tags: mfc, windbg

I am getting below call stack when debugging one of the crash dump which I got,

How to debug further for this call stack **ntdll!RtlDeactivateActivationContextUnsafeFast?**

```
# ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
00 002ceb10 76656d91 76682875 7668279d 002ceba0 ntdll!RtlDeactivateActivationContextUnsafeFast+0x209
01 002ceb14 76682875 7668279d 002ceba0 766827ad user32!UserCallWinProcCheckWow+0x13d
02 002ceb18 7668279d 002ceba0 766827ad a837dcf5 user32!_NLG_Return2
03 002ceb44 7668284d 766c0720 002cf934 fffffffe user32!_local_unwind4+0x80
04 002ceb58 766ba834 002cf944 766c0720 00000000 user32!_EH4_LocalUnwind+0x10
05 002ceb88 779133dd 002cebf8 002cf934 002ceca4 user32!_except_handler4+0x14f
06 002cebac 779133af 002cebf8 002cf934 002ceca4 ntdll!ExecuteHandler2+0x26
07 002cebd0 77913756 002cebf8 002cf934 002ceca4 ntdll!ExecuteHandler+0x24
08 002cef74 77923a9f 002cfacc 77923a9f 00000000 ntdll!RtlUnwind+0x147
09 002cef98 7792392b 00000000 00000000 00000000 ntdll!_EH4_GlobalUnwind+0x15
0a 002cefc0 779133dd fffffffe 002cfacc 002cf0fc ntdll!_except_handler4+0xe7
0b 002cefe4 779133af 002cf0ac 002cfacc 002cf0fc ntdll!ExecuteHandler2+0x26
0c 002cf008 77913350 002cf0ac 002cfacc 002cf0fc ntdll!ExecuteHandler+0x24
0d 002cf094 778c0133 002cf0ac 002cf0fc 002cf0ac ntdll!RtlDispatchException+0x127
0e 002cf094 77933f11 002cf0ac 002cf0fc 002cf0ac ntdll!KiUserExceptionDispatcher+0xf
0f 002cf5bc 7501544c 005707d0 14af5e6e 002cf614 ntdll!RtlDeactivateActivationContext+0x154
10 002cf5cc 547a9882 00000000 14af5e6e 05da3699 kernel32!DeactivateActCtx+0x31
11 002cf5d8 05da3699 a86ae6b6 054cadd0 0102f9a0 **mfc100u!AFX_MAINTAIN_STATE2::~AFX_MAINTAIN_STATE2+0x1d**
12 002cf614 0102fac1 00000000 00000040 00000000 **Mylib!MyClass::MyFunct**+0x79 
14 002cf778 548b4b4c 00000511 00000040 00069000 mfc100u!CWnd::OnWndMsg+0x2f5
15 002cf798 53fbd53b 00000511 00000040 00069000 mfc100u!CWnd::WindowProc+0x24
```

Comment: stack appears to be in unwind routine. did you try !analyze -v   and always post the os version ,  windbg version , os and windbg  bitness   if possible how the dump was captured  results of or summary of !analyze -v  etc if you expect some meaningful dialog  posting a stack without context   is not very useful

Comment: What's this code doing? **Mylib!MyClass::MyFunct**+0x79 ... It appears to be deallocating a class causing the exception.

Comment: @blabb  Yes I have done !analyze -v; OS version : Windows 7 Version 7601 (Service Pack 1); Windbg Version : 10.0.15063.137